# Read SMS and perform action

Tags: android

I have been searching for a long time but sadly I found no solution for my problem, or I just dont understand how to do that.
I want to read a sms and then do some stuff if the text equals my string text.
Broadcast Receiver is registered in manifest
When I erase the part where I ask for number, and just tell it to make a toast depending on the sms body, it works.

```
package com.journaldev.broadcastreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.SmsManager


public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String msg1 = "Testmessage 1";
    String msg2 = "Testmessage 2";
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

            if(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("01XXXX")) {
                String msg = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                if (msg == msg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, " Test 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //just an example for tests
                }
                else if (msg == msg2) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Test 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//just an example for tests
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `==` is not the way you can compare strings in Java

Answer (score 2):

String value comparision should use `mystr1.equals(mystr2)` or `mystr1.equalsIgnoreCase(mystr2)` function.

If you use `mystr1==mystr2` then you are checking for variables reference("pointer") to the same object instance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for help, comparing messages works now and I also found the problem with the Number.

It was:

```
if(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("01XXXX")) {
```

I changed it to:

```
if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number, sender)){
```

Here my full code:

```
package com.example.ossas.smsreader;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

String number = "0XXXX";
String msg1 = "Testmessage 1";
String msg2 = "Testmessage 2";
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs;

if (bundle != null) {
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

        if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number, sender)){
            String msg = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

        if (msg.equals(msg1)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Testmessage 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //just an example for tests

      } else if (msg.equals(msg2)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Testmessage 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//just an example for tests

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```